# Problem with File Manager Package in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-6, laravel-6.2

i'm using this Package [alexusmai/laravel-file-manager](https://github.com/alexusmai/laravel-file-manager)
which gave me a file manager, I integrated this package with TinyMCE 5.2.0

but I got a problem with image uploading

when I select an image from the file manager it doesn't appear in the editor...

[Image when i upload it using file manager package](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xLeSW.png)

Comment: What's the URL of the file in the database?  And have you run `php artisan storage:link`?

Comment: i didn't stored the image  in database+  i already run the commend